# TypeScript not recognizing mapped type with conditional types violation

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

I need help with these type definitions. TS is not showing me a warning but I believe I'm violating the type.

```js
type ElementType = "ShortText" | "Status" | "Number";

type BoardType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  columns: Array<ColumnType>;
};

type Column = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  element: ElementType;
};

type StatusType = Column & {
  options: { option: string; color: string }[];
};

type ColumnType = Column | StatusType;

type ColumnValue<T extends ElementType> = T extends "ShortText"
  ? string
  : T extends "Status"
  ? string
  : T extends "Number"
  ? number
  : never;

type PulseType<Columns extends ColumnType[]> = {
  id: string;
  board: string;
  data: {
    [K in Columns[number]["id"]]?: K extends Columns[number]["id"]
      ? ColumnValue<Extract<Columns[number], { id: K }>["element"]>
      : never;
  };
};

const board: BoardType = {
  id: "board-1",
  name: "Sample Board",
  columns: [
    { id: "Name", name: "Full Name", element: "ShortText" },
    {
      id: "Status",
      name: "To DOs",
      element: "Status",
      options: [
        { option: "To Do", color: "grey" },
        { option: "In Progress", color: "blue" },
        { option: "Done", color: "green" },
      ],
    },
    { id: "Age", name: "Age", element: "Number" },
  ],
};

const pulses: PulseType<typeof board.columns> = {
  id: "1",
  board: "board-1",
  data: {
    Name: "John Doe",
    Status: "Done",
    Age: 25,
    // Uncommented 'ehh', which is not a valid column ID
    ehh: "error", // Error: 'ehh' is not assignable to 'never'
  },
};
```

The goal is to have a board. In that board there's an array called `columns`. Based on the columns it should determine the type of a pulse. It's kind like a list and items.

In `BoardType` it takes an array of `ColumnType`, which is the union `Column | Status | Relationship`. The reason for this is basically, instead of keeping all the settings in the pulse, any common info is kept in the board. For example the status has options; those options are the same for each pulse in the board, so the options are kept in the column which is extended by `Status`.

The `ElementType` is just all the possible values of `board.columns[].element`.
`ColumnValue` is a conditional type that returns the type of each element

The issue I'm running into is, when I pass `PulseType` the argument, it doesn't enforce that the data object in it only has the keys of the ids in the board's column array.

As you see, the `ehh` property should cause TypeScript to give a warning, but it's not.

Comment: Can your code be slimmed down at all? There's quite a lot going on at the moment. Is it all required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK32DW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I shrunk the code only giving whats needed

Comment: @wonderflame ya it worked

Comment: okay, will write an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it won't be possible with the current board, since the compiler needs to know the exact shape of the `board`, which is impossible just by typing it as `BoardType`. Instead, we will need to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) that will prevent the compiler from widening the types to their primitives. With *const assertion* there will no longer be type checking, which can be fixed by using the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator. Since *const assertion* will turn every array to their read-only versions, we will need to update all array/tuple properties to become read-only:

```
type BoardType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  columns: readonly ColumnType[];
  groups?: readonly (readonly string[])[];
  access?: boolean;
  members?: readonly [{ id: string; access: readonly ['admin', 'viewer'] }];
  owner: string;
  apps?: readonly string[];
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
};

const board = {
  id: 'board-1',
  name: 'Sample Board',
  columns: [
    { id: 'Name', name: 'Full Name', element: 'string.ShortText' },
    { id: 'Age', name: 'Age', element: 'number.Number' },
  ],
  groups: [['Admins'], ['Editors', 'Viewers']],
  access: true,
  members: [{ id: 'user-1', access: ['admin', 'viewer'] }],
  owner: 'user-1',
  apps: ['app-1', 'app-2'],
  created_at: '2023-07-01',
  updated_at: '2023-07-15',
} as const satisfies BoardType;
```

In the *mapped type* instead of mapping through `Columns[number]["id"]]` just map through the whole elements (`Columns[number]`) and you can change the key to the value of `id` property by using the [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). There is also no point in checking if `K extends X` where `X` is what you are mapping. Since not all columns have `element` property, we will check whether the current item has this property and if it does then we will pass it to `ColumnValue`, otherwise the value will be `never`:

```
type PulseType<Columns extends readonly ColumnType[]> = {
  id: string;
  board: string;
  data: {
    [K in Columns[number] as K['id']]?: K extends {
      element: ElementType;
    }
      ? ColumnValue<K['element']>
      : never;
  };
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
};
```

Testing:

```
const pulses: PulseType<typeof board.columns> = {
  id: '1',
  board: 'board-1',
  data: {
    Name: 'John Doe',
    Age: +new Date(),
    ehh: 'error', // expected error
  },
  created_at: '2022-01-01',
  updated_at: '2022-01-01',
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgGwgFXNAvFAzsATnAOwHMoAfbPQogbQF0BuAKFEigAUIB7MJVVzHPmJ0mzNFACiSALYQCwPhkZQyUAOSCqAOgDKAC064FEAB7A1y1RsrEtAGU7Fkp85fLWhRXcACGwAK5YFirumrYAIn4QwVZhXhLSPogxoTZeAIJE0W7qBP7SAEYQuFpsBgTZIepxWgDGuBBRACYA+n4p1Wla-mBNzW2uVR7a8EgdanmFxVoAcvlFuOM1HNxjOcO2AEoQCH5wjlh6cGBqoizQAEKcPrhNilCYAN6WcE0AXBSeTCoEPrIfcW+UFqnAQ+QIWA+DR8TUcCBAUAAwqDwYoRJYiLhOD0sAB+KGNWEEeFQAAU0KJJLidAAlOiVD5arUIFg8R8CpxQY0CEDZFNcGyoBS4QjqI8oK8AWl6FBGczWQSYSKoNQ1DDpIQ1AAadQANzgEAA7sU1LQoABfBiWTiGiq4KVfSw+MBgQXC4kI6lWlT1RrACCtPwOqhAnp9f2B4DB4hMc1ncTIsHSAgPKDPFSSz4hyy-f5ZmOWHYQWTyD5SYtyBRoIFylmCr1AgNwYD4-M0b1QfVYOAFRDNkCthuMOOMMSsHS+AJYe6YRPgqAAMjT1rAwH2EI+4u4a4O0aIMpBCEMe4t6JHY+g212O4hRzAqbnycXy5UDQAZnvY0xzpJEogZ+oxZJAgiinBe7DlCg4iYGoYCQaB8asI+BAAchqgTn4gT3OQV57Acd6IdAyEAGo+GCEAADzIFALhyE0WCSDIlaKAAfKm1G0QQ9GdJ4ugGEYzhmDEuJtpYHwcWYdEMRsXgOE4LjCaJKjiTRklcdJNQYVOilxGJUASf66k8dokT+oppkQHpBlScZtiZJUUAiRZVmqYZ3EyVoCTAYpXn-mgLmce5kwLKUkGKWUjhQZAAVqe5NS+v07SWCJunKfprk2R5YaJYMjlKVAKmBRpXSjA5ImlYoMVudJwXTHM-KKbVuBVZlyxcDwZXsO1vD+Wl1lGR5uE3ocxw6WkekVLqxSEew-gIFgUWUchDFFUKhLKshaK0GxTwvO8bZAhyNz7YCljhj4m6WCo1AANISimy3UE1Zo+AxN2qq8pq0K2d2remKgA0WJZRoxFbyIoQIqOaV0AyJJFkf4lHvWoQOVqaLEw2lk3TZYI4+tCEYDJ+ljZYTQYHcOogghCwBQEdtypv9mZqPTTQALQAIzajmfwQB8ag6H8HVQFcx3cz6KLJpCKow+KzMzLz2pQLmfPqDAc0IFACuyErqOlrZXj6IYxhCRaWqyxK+1qPZSsq-zNs6nrIMTPMdWu4sZuWLQ5sqJi2Kuh81CqukTQahCpo6qqEhNM2hhBDqajEQaxoCl9PuykydYfHgiPp3yCzS2Klv84ExSc0rtYKiqaqh5qCf6kaJpmpa6c2naJcLbg5fp86AfV733fqAPABMEeWAlZPO8PAAMw8AMxs9PADsi9c+npMBkT6gz-Pi8rxzACs3PmrKDHUzg2B7Fgb4Ggxou3BDo7n7TYBzQt0tsG-i0UecnBvnT1xbh1ElhCHaL5i7qDXpYVm-NWbdzOn4C64CVDa1VmoAAUpwPQKZwicGiOnFQ9kPgAGoKiGigBZUkNICE0T0HofmxQsSLB1AAehYapSAtQIw0VwEw3G6cJ6b3JmoHew9V6r3FlADekZ+aiPEdPKBI4gA)